# How can I get the system key for Azure Function with custom domain for binding event grid trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I basically want to achieve what is described under this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=python#azure-cli) and I did stuck on the 'Get the system key' step. It does work for Azure Function without custom domain:

```
http://{functionappname}.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/systemkeys/eventgridextensionconfig_extension?code={masterkey}
```

but for any Azure Functions with custom domain it doesn't work. Response is not in expected format, it's just a static web site without the system key. Is there a way to get this key? I assume it might not be supported for such case.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are talking about the function app on azure.

Function key is just a valication method to let you hit the endpoint of the trigger. Custom domain or use original domain both can use function key.

Go to this place to get the key:

**trigger tier key:**

[image]

**function app tier key:**

[image]

You can even add your custom key.

Let me know whether this can answer your question.

Comment: I have the master key, the problem is that I cannot get the system key from GET request. In my case request uri is like: http://{functionappname}.{my custom domain}.net/admin/host/systemkeys/eventgridextensionconfig_extension?code={masterkey}. I don't use azurewebsites. How to get system key is mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=python#get-the-system-key

Comment: @MichaelK. Hi, any details? I use the link you give to get the system key and I can success get it. Can you show your response body?

Comment: for me it's a static html site with 404. Did it success for you for azure function with custom domain or azure domain?